# Как реализовать защиту от случайного закрытия вкладки?

Tags: javascript

Ситуация такова - работаю я, к примеру, 5 минут в редакторе в админке со статьей. Движок у меня самописный. Если вдруг случайно вкладку закрыть, изменения потеряются, да и никакого предупреждения об этом не будет. Думал, что смогу исправить это таким кодом:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) { 
    var conf = confirm('Действительно закрыть окно?');
    if(!conf) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Но он не работает, я так понял по сообщению в консоли, сам браузер блокирует этот код. Но как же тогда реализуют подобные штуки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так будет работать:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    return 'Действительно закрыть окно?'; // текст будет игнорироватся
});
```

Только текст будет игнорироваться, браузер подставить свой текст

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо. И на голом js тоже работает: `window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Действительно закрыть окно?";
};`